# I am having trouble with oracle

Tags: linux-kernel

Currently, I am having trouble installing Oracle Linux 9U1 on Vcenter while EVC mode is on and I get the error: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00007f00.

Is there any way to handle this error without having to turn off EVC mode on Vcenter?